# Slow Buffer in C#

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, buffer

I use a WebSocket to transfer data from an ESP to my C#-ConsoleApp. I get around 80 packages er second (every 12ms). I want to implement a buffer to have access to the last values. I implemented a kind of circular-buffer:

```
private byte BufferPointer;
private int[] RawValueBuffer;
private const byte BUFFER_SIZE = 100;

public void RawValue_Next(int newValue)
{
    if (BufferPointer >= BUFFER_SIZE)
    {
        BufferPointer = 0;
    }
    RawValueBuffer[BufferPointer] = newValue;
    BufferPointer++;
}

public int RawValue_Last()
{
    return RawValueBuffer[BufferPointer];
}
```

With this simple implementation I get a delay of around 1 second.
When I reduce the BUFFER_SIZE, the delay gets shorter.
When the value is stored directly in an integer-variable, everthing is fine.
I don't understand how this can happen.
The calculation of the address in the array should be a simple addition, right?
Printing the value in the console simply calls the `RawValue_Last()` function.

I overlook something obviously, but what?

Comment: "a delay of around 1 second" - where do you get this delay?

Comment: How many times are `RawValue_Next` called for each package? I.e. are you measuring a single call, or does your 1s figure represents millions of calls?

Comment: Also: your RawValue_Last() implementation seems wrong; it returns the  value of the slot where the next sample will be written not where the last sample was written. And it may throw an IndexOutOfRangeException.

Comment: @Klaus Gütter you are completely right. I do return the oldest, not the newest value. With a buffer-size of 100 and 80 packages per second, the function RawValue_Last() returns ~1sec old data. I was totally blind. Thanks a lot!!!